# How to use http://www.census.gov API to pull data

Tags: api, census

Am trying to query data from http://www.census.gov, using their API
I want to get the population of a particular city in the US, by using the city name and the US state code.

Given that I already have the key, what other parameters do I add in the URL below, so that I can get the population.

```
http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?key=<my key>
```

any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You probably shouldn't be exposing your key on a public site like StackOverflow or you may be violating census.gov's terms of use.

Comment: Also have you tried looking at examples and documentation here? http://www.census.gov/developers/

Comment: @jingtao The key in his query URI is the key used in the census developers examples. Either he has lightly perused the documentation or he is serving up a secondhand bowl of copypasta... At least he isn't exposing himself in public...

Comment: @Tonithy ah right, didn't know about the example key

Comment: @jingtao i have use the key that is found here http://www.census.gov/developers/ so as to not expose the one that i acquired. thanks for the observation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from your query URI, you wish to access population data from the 2010 Census Summary File. You would add GET paramaters of `get` and `for` to your query. Example:

```
http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?key=b48301d897146e8f8efd9bef3c6eb1fcb864cf&get=P0010001&for=state:06
```

The population table as given in the `get` parameter are identified with a "P" and you can use the `for` parameter to further narrow down your scope. Examples of valid criteria formatted as URIs can be found [here](http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1/geo.html)...

EDIT: It seems that for a finer grained search such as cities, you're going to need to use the governments cumbersome FIPS (Federal Information Processing Standard) codes (after converting lat/lon regions to their coding system)... I've found [this](http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/963) resource that should be helpful, specifically points 5 thru 7, but it seems mega complex...

Another alternative I found is the [USA Today census API](http://developer.usatoday.com/docs/read/Census), it seems that they mirror the data from the census and they do have available endpoints with data granularity at the city level... Check it out [here](http://developer.usatoday.com/docs/read/Census)...

Comment: yes, the url above takes me to the type of documentation am looking for however this particular documentation does not have an example of how to get the population of a city. example getting the population of Adamsville in the state Alabama (AL). FYI i have a database table that has the city names and the state code. i want to create a new column which will save the city populations.
at this point any documentation on how to handle the "city" parameter will be very appreciated.

Comment: @user2825816 Check the edits... For some reason the government doesn't consider cities to be an adequate level of demarcation. I suppose the census is taken on a county level, so it would probably require complex queries on their end to make it directly available and they opted to 'pass the buck' instead...

Comment: given the following url (http://www.census.gov/2010census/popmap/ipmtext.php?fl=01:0600394) one can get info on different cities/towns by changing the last set of numbers after the colon :
Example
http://www.census.gov/2010census/popmap/ipmtext.php?fl=01:0100124
http://www.census.gov/2010census/popmap/ipmtext.php?fl=01:0600394

Comment: http://www.census.gov/2010census/popmap/ipmtext.php?fl=01:0100820
the only problem is getting documentation on the numbers if any documentation exists at all.
there is also the option of using a bot to crawl the URL and pull the relevant data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to my link.  The census API is 'mega complex' but I think that is due to the complexity of the data it points to.

Comment: @mooreds No problem. Yeah, large caches of demographic data are pretty forced to be complex by nature.

Answer (score 1):

<del>no need to use API the data is available in CSV here http://www.census.gov/popest/data/cities/totals/2012/SUB-EST2012.html</del>

Comment: dead link; please fix.